# Is it correct to say: My study journey will be ended soon or My study journey is at its final stage

Tags: word-choice, expressions

Suppose that my study degree will be awarded soon. Is it correct to say that:

> **My study journey is at its final stage.**

or

> **My study journey will be ended soon.**

Any help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct.

**My study journey is at its final stage** emphasizes the final stage of the journey.

**My study journey will be ended soon** emphasizes the whole journey that will end soon.